# Making an element fill the rest of the width

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a system that allows me to attach additional styles on individual items, but renders the items sequentially without any way for me to introduce grouping a subset of items within the whole set. (So I can't wrap these subsets/groups in any element.)

It boils down essentially to this:

```
<span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span><span class="rest"></span>
<!-- There's not actually a line break here -->
<span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span><span class="rest"></span>
```

On top of that, the items before the one I'm trying to make span the rest of the line do not add up to a fixed with (which most hacks for this assume) so I can't say `calc(100% - 100px)` or anything like that.

I can break the line with `white-space: pre` and `\n` at the end of the content (that I can modify). I could even just dump a `<br />` in there - I can have extra HTML within the item - but I need the last item in the group to span all the way to the right so `background`/`border` could be applied to it etc.

I am looking to have multiple of these line-breaking elements, each of them starting at a different length from the start of the group. (This is not a table.)

I can apply styling to the container *all* of the elements are in, but again, can't wrap the individual groups.

I am not convinced this can be done given my constraints, but on the off chance it can - how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `float` properties with `white-space` and [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)*(block formating context)* :

> A block formatting context is a part of a visual CSS rendering of a Web page. It is the region in which the layout of block boxes occurs and in which floats interact with each other.

```css
span {
  float:left;
  white-space:pre-wrap;/* remove this to get the purpose */
}
.rest {
  background:gray;/* see me */
  float:none;/* prepare BFC */
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  min-height:1.2em;/* if empty, it needs some heights */
  margin-bottom:0.2em;/* or add it to height value */
}
```

```html
<span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span><span class="rest"></span>
<!-- There's not actually a line break here -->
<span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span><span class="rest"></span>
<span> whatever </span><span> else </span><span> what </span><span class="rest"></span>
```

Comment: This is amazing. Did not expect it to be even doable!